# When to charge for monthly usage at end of billing cycle in stripe

Tags: python, stripe-payments, webhooks

I have a subscription plan which costs $10/month per user plan + data "overage" charges. In other words, it is similar to (not unlimited) cell phone data plan.

When should I add in the monthly data usage at the end of the cycle?

According to [Subscription lifestyle documentation here](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/lifecycle#subscription_lifecycle), it says that the `invoice.created` event occurs roughly an hour before the `invoice.payment_succeeded` or `charge.succeeded`. However, it seems almost impossible to test this, as whenever an invoice is first created for a subscription, all the webhook events seem to fire simultaneously. How should this be dealt with? Note that I only want to update the `metered usage amount` one time, at the end of the cycle.

My code is currently something like this:

```
def stripe_webhook(request):

    if event_type == 'invoice.created':

        subscription_item_id = [item['subscription_item'] for item in stripe_data_obj['lines']['data'] if item['plan']['usage_type'] == 'metered'][0]

        data_usage = user.get_data_usage(start_date, end_date)
        usage = stripe.UsageRecord.create(
          quantity=data_usage,
          timestamp=int(time.time()),
          subscription_item=subscription_item_id,
          action = 'set'
        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to manually add line items to the invoice, then you can definitely test this. The idea would be to put your customer on a trial period for a few minutes. The first invoice created is for the trial and you can ignore that one and all related events. A few minutes later, when the trial period ends, a new invoice will be created and an `invoice.created` event will be sent to your endpoint. That one will allow you to modify the new invoice and add the extra amount/fees to charge this month.

To do this, you would use the Create Subscription [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_subscription) and pass the `trial_end` parameter as a unix timestamp representing a few minutes in the future.

Separately though, if you really want to report over-usage, you could use metered billing and usage records as documented here: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/metered-billing